# How to write junit test for after getting response in Android

Tags: android, junit, testcase

I have this below code.I want to write `junit` test for this method.

```
@Override
public void getSuccessData(Response response) {
    if(response.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
        BaseApplication.getInstance().setAccessToken(response.getToken().getAccessToken());
        commonNavigate.navigateToHomeScreen((HomeActivity)view);
    }
}
```

How can i write `junit` test case for this method.I am very new to `junit`.

Answer (score 0):

This is (most probably) a callback method you want to test.

If you want to *test a callback*, you would need to understand **mocking**.

In very basic terms, mocking lets you create a fake source object and invoke some request method on it, and then verify that a particular callback has been invoked with certain parameters. Read about **Mockito**, which can be easily integrated with Android Studio: http://site.mockito.org/

Secondly, you code calls **android-specific code**:

```
BaseApplication.getInstance().setAccessToken(response.getToken().getAccessToken());
            commonNavigate.navigateToHomeScreen((HomeActivity)view);
```

This code has dependency upon **Context** object. Please read what Context object means in Android and how it is shared in Application/Activity/View classes. "navigateToHomeScreen" method surely needs a Context!

Either you will **mock android dependencies** with fake objects, or you could run **Instrumented tests** which provide Context and other Android-framework-defendant objects.

To sum up - these are wide and complex topics and you should **make a research** on them first.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mockito framework if you want to test methods. You need to mock objects so that you can test the method with dummy response.

Please refer this link for mockito

```
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#setup
```